# Custom comparator for std::map not working

Tags: c++, dictionary, struct, std, stdmap

I experienced the following phenomenon when writing some C++ code:

I have a map looking like this:

```
std::map<test_struct_t*, unsigned int, cmp_by_value> testmap;
```

This map lies globally in my program and the struct is defined as:

```
struct test_struct_t {
  int x; int y; int val;

  bool operator<(const test_struct_t &o) const {
      return x < o.x || y < o.y || val < o.val;
  }
  test_struct_t(int a, int b, int c) : x(a), y(b), val(c) {}
};
```

The custom comparator I wrote is:

```
struct cmp_by_value {
  bool operator()(const test_struct_t *a, const test_struct_t *b) const 
  {
      return *a < *b;
  }
};
```

Now, in my main method I do the following:

```
testmap.insert({new test_struct_t(0, 0, 2 ), 6});
testmap.insert({new test_struct_t(0, 1, 2 ), 6});
testmap.insert({new test_struct_t(1, 1, 0 ), 6});
testmap.insert({new test_struct_t(1, 2, 0 ), 6});
testmap.insert({new test_struct_t(2, 1, 0 ), 6});
testmap.insert({new test_struct_t(1, 2, 1 ), 6});
testmap.insert({new test_struct_t(1, 2, 0 ), 6});
```

And then I print the values in the map with some format method:

```
std::string format(test_struct_t *e) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "(" << e->x << "," << e->y << ") = " << e->val;
    return ss.str();
}
```

And in the main:

```
std::map<test_struct_t*, unsigned int>::iterator it;
  for (it = testmap.begin(); it != testmap.end(); ++it) {
      std::cout << format(it->first) << std::endl;
 }
```

My program gives the following output:

```
(1,1) = 0
(1,2) = 0
(1,2) = 1
(2,1) = 0
(1,2) = 0
(0,0) = 2
(0,1) = 2
```

Can anyone explain to me why there is the duplicate entry "(1,2) k =0"? When I remove one of the other inserted statements, everything is fine and there is no duplicate. Any ideas?

EDIT: What I also found very interesting is that:

```
testmap[new test_struct_t(0, 0, 2 )] = 6;
testmap[new test_struct_t(0, 1, 2 )] = 6;
testmap[new test_struct_t(1, 1, 0 )] = 6;
testmap[new test_struct_t(1, 2, 0 )] = 6;
testmap[new test_struct_t(2, 1, 0 )] = 6;
testmap[new test_struct_t(1, 2, 1 )] = 6;
testmap[new test_struct_t(1, 2, 0 )] = 6;
```

Gives this:

```
(0,0) = 2
(1,1) = 0
(1,2) = 0
(0,1) = 2
```

Comment: First thing to do would be to check if it works for `std::map<test_struct_t, unsigned int>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [STL map custom comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558273/stl-map-custom-comparator)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `operator<` does not define a strict weak ordering. Try

```
bool operator<(const test_struct_t &o) const {
   return std::tie(x,y,val)<std::tie(o.x,o.y,o.val);
}
```

Comment: Oh well, thank you...this works...can you maybe explain a little bit more why?

Comment: @今天春天 Imagine two structs `(a)` and `(b)` with x and y values equal to (1, 2) and (2, 1) respectively (ingnore `val` existence). Now check if `(a) < (b)`: `1 < 2 || 2 < 1 => true || false => true`. Now check if `(b) < (a)`: `2 < 1 || 1 < 2 => false || true => true`. So each one is less (should go before) than the other! This is impossible, so everything breaks.